# Apply Standard Design Community Tokens in the Lightning Web Component (LWC)

Tags: salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, lwc

As per the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_communities.htm, I want to use community tokens in the Lightning Web Component (LWC).

In the LWC CSS file, I have applied the textTransform token as,

```
.cssClass{
    text-transform: var(--lwc-textTransform);
}
```

While saving the LWC, an error is occurring **No TOKEN named textTransform found**.
How can I use the textTransform token in the LWC?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was available for Aura components only and is not marked as Global within the definition,

As per below link:

Lightning web components can use any Lightning Design System design token marked Global Access. If you get the error: No TOKEN named tokenName found, it's likely that you're using a token that isn't marked Global Access. Either use a global token or use a custom Aura design token.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_design_tokens